How to sign XML document created using XmlSerializer and autogenerated classes from xsd.exe
I am having problems signing XML file created using auto-generated classes using xsd.exe on XML Schema.
My schema looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="TestXml"
    targetNamespace="TestXml.xsd"
    xmlns="TestXml.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
>
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="PackageEnvelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Package">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:unsignedInt"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AdditionalElement" type="xs:boolean"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="dsig:Signature" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


The way I create the signed XML is the following:
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PackageEnvelope packageEnvelope = new PackageEnvelope
            {
                Package = new PackageEnvelopePackage
                {
                    AdditionalElement = true,
                    Message = "Some message",
                    Status = 1
                }
                // , Signature = <XML Signature fields I am not using. Should I?>
            };

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PackageEnvelope));


            using (var fileStream = File.Create("D://Project//TestCreatedXml.xml"))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, packageEnvelope);
            };

            System.Console.WriteLine("Finished !");


            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("D://Project//TestCreatedXml.xml");

            
            var cert = GetSignature();

            doc = SignXml(doc, cert);

            doc.Save("D://Project//SignedTestCreatedXml.xml");
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 GetSignature()
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert;

            using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "xxxxxxxx", true);

                if (certificates.Count != 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Certificate not found!");
                }

                cert = certificates[0];
            }

            return cert;
        }

        public static XmlDocument SignXml(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain));

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc)
            {
                SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(),
                KeyInfo = keyInfo
            };

            Reference reference = new Reference()
            {
                Uri = ""
            };

            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());

            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement signatureElement = signedXml.GetXml();
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(signatureElement, true));

            return doc;

        }

The generated Signed XML file looks like the following:

When I try to validate the format of the document it throws an error that Signature element is not declared, but as you can see, it is. My guess is that when SignedXml is computing the signature it adds default namespace to the the Signature element like in the picture, but in my TestXml.xsd schema there is already an import on the http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# schema.
On the generated class from xsd.exe there is a field for Signature element. Am I supposed to sign it that way?

"Am I supposed to sign it that way?" - Why not just give it a try? Worst thing that can happen is that it still doesn't work.

@Fildor how? What types are they? Tried creating SignedInfo element and assigning it to SignedInfo field, and it said incompatible type

Ah, so that's where the problem is?

@Fildor I cannot sign the document properly be it with SignedXml or using the Signiture field on the generated class from xsd.exe. I have been searching the internet but have not been able to find solution. When I sign using SignedXml it says the document doesn't conform to the XML Schema. Using the auto-generated classes and XmlSerializer, I don't know how to properly set up the sub-fields of the Signature.

Can you add the generated XML as text, rather than an image?
